# how to access upload images

Tags: python, django, templates

```
I am creating one app using following two url's , homepage.html and detail.html.

*models.py*

class News(models.Model):
  primary_image = models.ImageField("Main Image ",upload_to = "static/uploadedImg/main",)
  secondary_Image = models.ImageField("Sub Image",upload_to = "static/uploadedImg/sub",)
```

In settings.py I had defined MEDIA and MEDIA_ROOT

I want to display random primary_image in homepage.html with primary_image as a link.

```
*articles.html*

    <div id = "randommainImage">
         <a href = "#"><img src = "{{random_object.primary_image}}"></a>
    </div>

 NewArticles 
 articles
 db.sqlite3
 manage.py
 media
 NewsArticles
 README.md
 static

NewsArticles\articles
admin.py
forms.py
models.py
static
Templates
tests.py
urls.py
views.py
```

Also, I want to display both primary_image & secondary_Image in a detail.html
  Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you have these in your settings properly then you're ready to go:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

A folder called `media` will be created to upload all the images in that folder.
Your image fields should look like this, I don't get why are you creating a folder for them in the static folder..

```
primary_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploadedImg/main/')
secondary_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploadedImg/sub/')
```

So your primary image will be in `media/uploadedImg/main/img.png`

View can look like:

```
def index(request):
    context_dict = {}

    news = News.objects.all()
    context_dict['news '] = news 

    return render(request, 'index.html', context_dict, )
```

And to get the primary image you'll use `{{ news.primary_image.url }}` in your template.

edit>

Add this in your urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings

# ... your normal urlpatterns here

if settings.DEBUG:
    # static files (images, css, javascript, etc.)
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

Comment: File "C:\Python27\Scripts\NewsArticles\NewsArticles\settings.py", line 20
    SECRET_KEY = 
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I am getting this message after changing path

Comment: Could you paste `settings.py` bit that shows your media setup, and your secret key [WITHOUT THE KEY IT SELF], because you have a syntax error in the `SECRET_KEY`

Comment: I am getting this error message C:\Python27\Scripts\media\uploadedImg\main exists and is not a directory.

Comment: @KiranN Try my edit first. This tutorial will help you understand how to set it up correctly, http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/templates_static.html#the-static-media-server Since there are errors keep popping, I can't really say how does your settings.py and other files look like so the best best is to read up the tutorial and it will teach you how to set up everything around `static/` and your image folders.

Answer (score 0):

If you've defined correctly **MEDIA** and **MEDIA_ROOT**, to display the first image in the **article.html** template you use:

```
<img src = "{{ MEDIA_ROOT }}{{ random_object.primary_image }}" />
```

and likewise in the **detail.html** template:

```
<img src = "{{ MEDIA_ROOT }}{{ random_object.primary_image }}" />
<img src = "{{ MEDIA_ROOT }}{{ random_object.secondary_image }}" />
```

Comment: Still its not displaying , I am getting this path in firebug  "static/uploadedImg/main/ezgif.com-crop.gif"

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
Is this correct path right

Comment: 06-Dec-15  07:46 PM    <DIR>          articles
06-Dec-15  07:45 PM            65,536 db.sqlite3
02-Dec-15  08:48 PM               255 manage.py
06-Dec-15  05:27 PM    <DIR>          media
06-Dec-15  07:43 PM    <DIR>          NewsArticles
03-Dec-15  08:43 PM                18 README.md
06-Dec-15  04:49 PM    <DIR>          static

Comment: @KiranN put the code in your question, not in a comment

Comment: admin.py
admin.pyc

models.py models.pyc
static Templates
tests.py
03-Dec-15  11:24 PM               197 tests.pyc
05-Dec-15  08:37 PM               733 urls.py
urls.pyc views.py
views.pyc

Comment: I am getting this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/static/uploadedImg/main/1c994b663d6049e6bcdf11e9db9231f4.jpg